# eclipse pipe stdout to another project

Tags: java, eclipse, stream, pipe

I have two projects in eclipse;

Project A is constantly streaming (currently to STDOUT) output (each new value streamed is newline delimited)

Project B I want to take in this, and do some stuff with it etc,

The only way I have found to do this is by writing to a file; I would prefer to avoid this as there is a ridiculous amount of data (at least for my resources), and most of it will end up being tossed.

Any advice appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do they need to be separate projects? Or can they be separate threads (in the same project)? If they can be separate threads (in the same project), you may benefit greatly by using a `BlockingQueue`.

Comment: Hmmm...this is definitely something I could consider. I will definitely look into this for now; thank you!

Comment: After consideration it is necessary for there to be two seperate projects. any advice appreciated

Comment: The fact that you're coding in eclipse has nothing to do with this question, I think you should remove eclipse from the question.

Answer (score 1):

There are several methods of approaching this:

1. Using TCP socket - not that difficult to achieve and gives you the ability to work remotely (run each program on a different computer).
2. Create a segmented file by program A and consume them with program B - The nuances are a bit tricky but overall a robust technique if it suits your needs
3. Use OS pipes - the easiest method given your current situation

I'll demonstrate option 3.

ProgramA.java:

```java
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

ProgramB.java:

```java
java.io.BufferedReader br = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(System.in));
String input;
while((input=br.readLine())!=null){
    System.out.println("----" + input);
}
```

After which you can do this at the command line:

```bsh
java -cp <program_A_classpath> ProgramA | java -cp <program_B_classpath> ProgramB
```

Output will be:

```
----0
----1
----2
----3
----4
----5
----6
----7
----8
----9
```